Can you achieve 3 attacks using Dual Wield [Feat], light weapons, and nick?
I had a discussion regarding dual wielding, light weapons and nick - that stated a properly built rouge could get up to 3 attacks per round by level 4.   So this is a viability check on that process / theory.

Light Weapon Property (p213): When you take the Attack action on your turn and attack with a Light weapon, you can make one extra attack as a Bonus Action later on the same turn.  That attack must be made with a different light weapon, and you don't add your ability modifier.

Nick (weapon property) (p214): When you make the extra attack of the Light Property, you can make it as part of the Attack action instead of as a Bonus Action.  You can make this extra attack only once per turn.  (Requires Weapon Mastery).

Dual Wielder [General Feat] (p203): When you take the attack action on your turn and attack with a weapon that has the Light Property, you can make one extra attack as a Bonus Action Later on the same turn with a different weapon, which must be a melee weapon that lacks the Two Handed Property.


Items used:
Primary Weapon:  Short Sword (Light / Vex)
Secondary Weapon: Scimitar (light / Nick)
Sequence of events:

Primary attack with Short Sword - Triggers extra attack of the Scimitar's Nick.
Attack with Scimitar during the attack action, no more nick attacks.
Using the Dual Wielding Feat - we trigger a third attack using our bonus action with the Short Sword (Since it's different from the scimitar).

A triggers B, B then triggers A.  No conflict due to the short sword not being the scimitar and vice versa.  Only one nick attack and one bonus action used.
There was mention of some interview with a game dev saying thats as intended, but I havent been able to google that up.
So - yes, that's the viability check.  Is this correct and accurate?  Is there an easier way to explain this?

I guess the core question is whether the extra attack of the Dual Wielder feat counts as "the extra attack of the Light Property". After reading the relevant bits quoted here and checking the PHB for any additional context... I'm not sure.

Yes
I think you've already answered your own question, but I'll leave a few hints and my own explanation here:

The "extra attack only once per turn" in the Nick Mastery Property refers to the extra attack granted by the Light property. Nick doesn't provide a new extra attack; it shifts the extra attack of the Light property from a Bonus Action to an extra attack and adds a restriction to it: "You can make this extra attack only once per turn".

Because of the previous rule, if you use Nick, you can only make the Light property's extra attack once per turn.

The Dual Wielder feat provides another source for a bonus action attack, separate from both Light and Nick.


Resources explaining the intent

The pre-release article, Your Guide to Weapon Mastery in the 2024 Player's Handbook, explains how Nick works (emphasis mine):


To explain the Nick property, we should briefly cover that being able
to attack twice while dual-wielding Light weapons has subtly changed
in the 2024 Player’s Handbook. Instead of being covered under Melee
Attacks, the rules for dual-wielding Light weapons are covered under
the Light weapon property.
It still functions the same way: When you make an attack with a weapon
that has the Light property, you can use a Bonus Action to make one
attack with a different Light weapon you’re wielding.
The Nick mastery property allows you to make the additional attack you
receive from wielding two Light weapons as part of the initial attack
action.
Keep in mind that this doesn’t mean you can make a third attack as a
Bonus Action, as the Light property specifies you only get one extra
attack. But, while it may not pump your damage, this frees up your
Bonus Action to use class/species abilities, such as the Rogue’s
Cunning Action, while still getting an additional attack in.


The next video explains well the interaction between the Light weapon property, Dual Wielder feat, Two-Weapon Fighting Style feat, and Nick Weapon Mastery: Why You Get 4 Attacks a Round by Level 5

